# How to take separate each value from the first of a list

Tags: python

I have the following list resulting from this code:

> `section[0:1]`

which results in the following element:

> [start:(81979.67599999905 432187.33199999854)end:(81980.92700000107 432188.0320000015)]

How can I access the first and the second element of this first row i.e.,
81979.67599999905 and 
432187.33199999854.

`type(section)` is a list

Comment: What is this `[start:(81979.67599999905 432187.33199999854)end:(81980.92700000107 432188.0320000015)]` str ?

Comment: to answer Han's question, maybe use "type(section[0])"

Comment: Is `[start:(81979.67599999905 432187.33199999854)end:(81980.92700000107 432188.0320000015)]` a `str` or a list of `tuples`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the result to `str` and then use the `re` package:

```
import re

section_str = 'start:(81979.67599999905 432187.33199999854)end:(81980.92700000107 432188.0320000015)'
# Replace the last line by the next one
#section_str = str(section[0:1])
r = re.compile('start:\((.*?)\)end:')
m = r.search(section_str)
if m:
    result = m.group(1)
    print(result.split(' ')[0])
    print(result.split(' ')[1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
81979.67599999905
432187.33199999854
```

Answer (score 0):

`section[0:1]` return list of 1 element, so better way is to acces this element by `section[0]` then:

Assuming that

```
[start:(81979.67599999905 432187.33199999854)end:(81980.92700000107 432188.0320000015)]
```

is a string, you can try:

```
first = a.split('(')[1].split(' ')[0]
second = a.split('(')[1].split(' ')[1].split(')')[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> first
'81979.67599999905'
>>> second
'432187.33199999854'
```